# Is there a formula for the number of elements in $S_n$ having length $k$ with respect to the generators taken to be the transpositions?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups

Define the length of a permutation as the minimum number of adjacent transpositions needed to describe it.
We know that there is only one element of length $0$ in $S_n$ and $n-1$ elements of length $1$ and one element of maximum length $\ell_n$.
Is there a formula that give the number of elements in $S_n$ having a length $k$ where $0<k<\ell_n$?

Comment: It seems like something is missing here. Please edit.

Comment: Actually, if you write a permutation as cycles, the length of a cycle of length $a$ is $a-1$, and the length of the whole thing is the sum of the lengths. So maximum length is acchieved if there is one cycle of length $n$, and there are $(n-1)!$ such elements. I guess, you are talking about transpositions of neighbours instead.

Answer (score 11):

I assume you are considering the symmetric groups ${\rm S}_n$ with
generating sets $\{(i,i+1) \ | \ i < n\}$ (since in this case you have
$n-1$ elements of length $1$ and one element of maximum length, as you
state in your question), and ask for the number of elements of ${\rm S}_n$
of given length with respect to this set of generators. --
Then the numbers you are looking for are the so-called
[Mahonian numbers](https://oeis.org/A008302) $M(r,c)$ which are the coefficients in the
expansion of the product
$$
  \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1 + x + \dots + x^i).
$$

Comment: I see that "Mahonian" = in honor of MacMahon; is that a common formation?  (Cf. Descartes → cartesian, but Desargues → Desarguesian [though "Arguesian" is occasionally seen too].)

Comment: This product is also called the Poincaré series  of the Coxeter system $S_n$ ...

Comment: Thank you all. Yes Stephan, this is exactly what I meant. Do you know a good reference for the information you posted? Thanks in advance

Comment: @M.T: A reference is for example: T. Kyle Petersen,
[*Eulerian Numbers*](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9781493930906), Birkhäuser, 2015,
[Page 96](https://books.google.de/books?id=v_64CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=%22Mahonian+numbers%22&source=bl&ots=4f9YsJfpym&sig=JgEZ03lY25_D24yyyrDCEP2xdp8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjThK3y2pXMAhUDkywKHUaFAA8Q6AEIUzAG#v=onepage&q=%22Mahonian%20numbers%22&f=false).